# Nao consigo imprimir os valores do meu Array.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Não estou conseguindo imprimir os valores adicionados a meu Array no Console.
A resposta do Console ficar vazia como se não tivesse adicionado os valores ao Array. Abaixo segue o código e o Documento XML.

**Bloco do Codigo:**

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
          var Gostei = []; // Array que vai armazenar as notas boas
         $.ajax({
                  url:'NotasPorMes.xml',
                  dataType: 'xml',
                  success: function(xml){
                        $(xml).find('list').each(function() {
                        $(this).find('NotasPorMes').each(function(){
                        // Adicionando os valores de Gostei para o Array
                        Gostei.push([$(this).find('Gostei').text()]);
                        });     
                   });   
                },
                   // Se nao consegui ler o arquivo xml, exibo mensagem de erro no console
                   error: function () {
                      console.log("Ocorreu um erro inesperado durante o processamento.");
                    }
       });
       console.log(Gostei); //Imprime o valor do Array
    });
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<list>
  <NotasPorMes>
    <Mes>1</Mes>
    <Gostei>9</Gostei>
    <NaoGostei>6</NaoGostei>
    <Total>7</Total>
  </NotasPorMes>
  <NotasPorMes>
    <Mes>8</Mes>
    <Gostei>6</Gostei>
    <NaoGostei>9</NaoGostei>
    <Total>7</Total>
  </NotasPorMes>
  <NotasPorMes>
    <Mes>6</Mes>
    <Gostei>4</Gostei>
    <NaoGostei>9</NaoGostei>
    <Total>8</Total>
  </NotasPorMes>
</list>
```

O valor só é imprimido se eu colocar o `console.log(Gostei);` dentro do `bloco $(this).find('NotasPorMes').each( function(){...});`, Sendo que o objetivo do código é percorrer o xml adicionar os valores ao array e depois retorna esse array com seus valores para devido tratamento fora do bloco `$.ajax({...});`.

Espero ter sido bem claro, conto com a ajuda de vocês, Obrigado.

Comment: troca a criação do array, tira o var. ex: "Gostei=[];"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está ocorrendo é que sua requisição AJAX é `assíncrona`, o que quer dizer que quando fizer a requisição o javascript não irá "esperar" a solicitação ser concluída para executar o próximo bloco de código.

Você pode tornar sua requisição `síncrona` alterando a propriedade `assync`para `false`.

Caso queira entender melhor, segue a [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) em inglês.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'NotasPorMes.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    async: false  
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Pedro Camara Junior, é realmente o problema era no assync. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece pois o método `$.ajax` é assíncrono por padrão, ou seja, ela irá rodar em paralelo, e o seu `console.log(Gostei);` vai ser executado antes de ele terminar.

Como alternativa você dizer para o método $.ajax que você não quer que ele seja assíncrono passando `async: false` nas opções:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          var Gostei = []; // Array que vai armazenar as notas boas
         $.ajax({
                  url:'NotasPorMes.xml',
                  dataType: 'xml',
                  async: false,
                  success: function(xml){
                        $(xml).find('list').each(function() {
                        $(this).find('NotasPorMes').each(function(){
                        // Adicionando os valores de Gostei para o Array
                        Gostei.push([$(this).find('Gostei').text()]);
                        }); 
                        console.log(Gostei); //Imprime o valor do Array    
                   });   
                },
                   // Se nao consegui ler o arquivo xml, exibo mensagem de erro no console
                   error: function () {
                      console.log("Ocorreu um erro inesperado durante o processamento.");
                    }
       });

    });
```

Ou colocar o log para dentro da função de sucesso:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          var Gostei = []; // Array que vai armazenar as notas boas
         $.ajax({
                  url:'NotasPorMes.xml',
                  dataType: 'xml',
                  success: function(xml){
                        $(xml).find('list').each(function() {
                        $(this).find('NotasPorMes').each(function(){
                        // Adicionando os valores de Gostei para o Array
                        Gostei.push([$(this).find('Gostei').text()]);
                        }); 
                        console.log(Gostei); //Imprime o valor do Array    
                   });   
                },
                   // Se nao consegui ler o arquivo xml, exibo mensagem de erro no console
                   error: function () {
                      console.log("Ocorreu um erro inesperado durante o processamento.");
                    }
       });

    });
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas resposta Fernando Mondo, é realmente eu esqueci desse detalhe do ajax. Testei com assincrono falso é resolveu o problema. Obrigado pela sua ajuda.